# Is there any example for jasper reports where parameters can be taken from a controller to jrxml

Tags: java, xml

Say i am having a jsp page and want to get the values from the inputbox as well as the drop down. This page is directed to a controller. I want to get the values from the controller to jrxml and to generate pdf report from it.
I couldn't find a proper solution for this problem. If there is any example that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have got values from the input box as well as the drop down box to the controller's addData method. In the controller you can create a Hash map and put those 2 values you have taken.

```
public void addData(val1,val2){
    Map<String,Object> param=new HashMap();
    //these inputBox and dropDown are the parameters specified in the .jrxml file.
    param.put("inputBox", val1);
    param.put("dropDown", val1);
    //Now compile the jrxml file giving the relative path. This will create a .jasper file in the same folder
    JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("src/Forms/newReport.jrxml");
    //Now compile the created .jasper(Which is created while compiling .jrxml)
    //For this you pass the hash map
    JasperPrint jasperPrint= JasperFillManager.fillReport("src/Forms/newReport.jasper", param);
    //Now the parameters in the .jasper file will be set to the values in hash map.
}
```